# RasPi Drive RB-01 C073A

Tags: electronics, dc-motor

Does anyone have info on the RasPi Drive electronic controller motor Driver? I can't find information on how it should be connected between the RP 3 and a small DC motor.

Comment: Are you talking about the "Allegro A3967 Easy Driver" usually for controlling stepping motors?  (1) https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12779
(2) https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/easy-driver-hook-up-guide/all, (3) https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/A3967.pdf.

Comment: Does your module look something like these? (4) https://www.aliexpress.com/popular/a3967-module.html. And if you are not micro steppingly drive a step motor, I would recommend L298N or L293D which can drive both DC and stepper motors, and more newbie friendly. A3967 mcirostepping driver is a bit hard for newbies, and that is why you don't find too much info on A3967, which was once popular, but not so nowadays.  L298N, on the other hand, is trendy, so you can find lots of tutorials for newbies.

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't the a3967 module.  However, I just found it on Amazon.  I'll track down a schematic from there.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You might like to give me the web link if you wish to have more suggestions.

Comment: Or this one, actually ussingL293D?
http://www.alsrobot.cn/wiki/index.php/SKU:RB-01C073A_%E6%A0%91%E8%8E%93%E6%B4%BE%E7%94%B5%E6%9C%BA%E9%A9%B1%E5%8A%A8%E6%9D%BF

Comment: We need a link to the specs of the device you mean.  It wastes our time to have to guess.

Comment: Or this guy? https://www.amazon.com/RasPiDrive-RasPiRobot-Board-Raspberry-Driver/dp/B01DR385LC.